# ¿Cómo hacer iterable el primer numero de un range en Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Buenos días y feliz fin de semana a todos,

Estoy haciendo un programa que solicite al usuario que introduzca un número entero positivo (n) y genere un diccionario (cubes) en el que las claves sean los números del 1 al n -en orden creciente- y los valores sean los cubos de dichos números.

```
n = int(input('n: '))

cubes = {n:n**3 for n in range (1, n)}

print(cubes)
```

El problema que tengo es que no logro hacer iterable (no sé si es el término correcto) el 1 del rango (1, n).
Entiendo el porqué, dado que al final el programa lee un rango 1,1 donde no hay nada, 0.
Pero cambiando a (0,n) tampoco me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a todos!!

Comment: Hola. Te escribo un comentario en esta pregunta porque la pregunta a la que me quiero referir está cerrada y retirada y por tanto no se puede. Es otra pregunta tuya, este es el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/523162/cómo-de-difícil-os-parece-este-este-problema aunque sólo usuarios con suficiente reputación o tú mismo podrán leerla. Solo quería comentarte al respecto de esa pregunta que la redacción de la misma era muy desafortunada. El problema de programación en sí no es tan difícil. Básicamente lo que necesitas hacer es convertir una ecuación matemática en una expresión python

Comment: No tienes por qué saber lo que es una "funcion pdf" ni una "distribución gaussiana" ni esas cosas que suenan a chino. Tampoco tienes por qué saber interpretar la fórmula matemática que aparece en el enunciado, ni que en esa fórmula el símbolo σ representa al parámetro `var` o que el símbolo μ representa al parámetro `mean`. O que el símbolo `e` elevado a lo que sea es lo mismo que la función `math.exp()`

Comment: Pero una vez que sabes esas cosas, lo que tienes que hacer es implementar en python la fórmula, que quedaría así: `return 1/math.sqrt(2*math.pi*var)*math.exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*var))`. En resumen, la pregunta era difícil por incomprensible, no porque la programación necesaria fuese compleja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `range` se termina al llegar al valor final. La revisión se hace antes de empezar cada iteración.

Todo lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar el valor final; en este caso, tu límite es `n + 1`

```
n = int(input('n: '))

cubes = {n:n**3 for n in range (1, n + 1)}

print(cubes)
```

Comment: Toda una tarde para resolverlo y era poner un +1... Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @Feijoo_Progamming_Enterprise. Es un error que nos perseguirá toda la vida.